# TortoiseSVN Committing To Multiple Targets

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I use TortoiseSVN as my version control tool. I recently created a command line to commit changed files to the SVN repository.

My repository is located here: `file:///F:/SVNRepository/TortoiseSVN`

My source code file is located here: `C:\Users\userid\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts\`

If I go to Windows Explorer and right click on the file I see the following, which is correct:

[image: Windows Explorer Commit Command]

However, if I run the TortoiseSVN command I see the following:

[image: Multiple targets and duplicates my files]

Notice how the Commit To: says (multiple targets selected) and you see a duplicate of all the files.

I searched for hours now and can't seem to find out how to have the TortoiseSVN Commit Command show correctly.

Here is how I coded the command:

```
'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe' '/command:commit' '/path:"C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts\*.*"'
```

Here is the result of the `svn info` command:

```
C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts\TortoiseSVN>svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts
URL: file:///F:/SVNRepository/TortoiseSVN
Relative URL: ^/TortoiseSVN
Repository Root: file:///F:/SVNRepository
Repository UUID: fd12eeda-107f-5d40-bebd-932aaf916f88
Revision: 11
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: zrmfld
Last Changed Rev: 11
Last Changed Date: 2015-10-20 13:31:07 -0400 (Tue, 20 Oct 2015)
```

Comment: please, show output of `svn info` in `C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts\`

Comment: @Lazybadger
C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts\TortoiseSVN>svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts
URL: file:///F:/SVNRepository/TortoiseSVN
Relative URL: ^/TortoiseSVN
Repository Root: file:///F:/SVNRepository
Repository UUID: fd12eeda-107f-5d40-bebd-932aaf916f88
Revision: 11
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: zrmfld
Last Changed Rev: 11
Last Changed Date: 2015-10-20 13:31:07 -0400 (Tue, 20 Oct 2015)

Comment: @LazyBadger check the edits to my question where I include svn info

Comment: and please `svn ls` for the same dir

Comment: In my experience, you can just do a commit. Even with multiple files shown, the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't know why you used apostrophes around each part of TortoiseProc command, according to [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) (for CMD-shell ?) it isn't needed (note the first sample in the bottom on page with TortoiseProc's commit)
2. For`:commit` command "...The /path specifies the target directory or the list of files to commit...", i.e "all (changed versioned) files in dir" may be just

`/path:"C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts\"`

3. `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\` usually added to PATH, TortoiseProc can be called from any location, thus: you can in script have smth. more readable like

> ```
> cd C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts
> TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"." ...
> ```

**Last but not least**:

Easy and good automation of SVN-activities assumes using of *fully non-interactive* CLI-tools, which you can have as part of TortoiseSVN installation: easy and transparent syntax, no dialogues|windows, read `svn help commit`

Comment: Okay you solved my problem. It appears that if you set the /path to "C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts\" it works, but if do it like I did it, which was "C:\Users\zrmfld\Documents\ActiveDocuments\PSScripts\*.*" it will show you the (multiple targets selected).

As for the single quotes, around the commands, they exists because I was trying to run these commands from a PowerShell console.

Thanks again --- you  saved the day!

Comment: @FrankDiJohn - cool. I still recommend to migrate to *pure CLI-tools*